# Interpreting TCP Traceroute results here?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ssh, unix, sftp

I used to be able to connect via `SFTP` to a remote server to download files. Our local server is `Windows 2008 Enterprise` and the remote server is Unix. The local computer and the remote server are under the same network/domain. Out of the blue, I was unable to connect.

Now, Please keep in mind that this is a multi-national company and someone somewhere at someplace could have added a rule and we wouldn't know about it. I cannot fix the issue, but when I create the ticket I can be more specific as to where the actual problem is. My goal is to create the ticket by specifying what IP/server is blocking our access to the sftp server.

So I posted this issue here and someone suggested that I use `tracetcp` because it may tell me where the actual block is from the 12 hops seen in `tracert`. After I see the results of `tracetcp`, I ask him what the difference between this and `telnet`, since both seem to return the same thing, except with different wording and that `tracetcp` continues to try.

So this is what I've done.

I pinged the server and no packet loss: `Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`.

I ran a tracert and  this is the result:

```
Tracing route to server-test.net.companyws.com [31.129.173.86]

over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  205.166.78.128
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  157.88.229.249
  3    28 ms    31 ms    28 ms  50.22.154.11
  4    81 ms    79 ms    79 ms  63.5.170.209
  5     *        *        *     55.122.96.123
  6     *        *        *     156.213.48.174
  7     *        *        *     197.98.12.60
  8     *        *        *     82.64.244.32
  9    98 ms    98 ms    98 ms  230.67.160.132
 10    98 ms   100 ms    98 ms  154.134.127.203
 11   102 ms    99 ms   102 ms  156.26.214.219
 12    98 ms    98 ms    98 ms  31.129.173.86

Trace complete.
```

I ran telnet and this is the result:

```
telnet 31.129.173.86 22
Connecting To 31.129.173.86...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22:
Connect failed
```

Finally, I ran a tracetcp and this was the result:

```
tracetcp 31.129.173.86:22

Tracing route to 31.129.173.86 on port 22
Over a maximum of 30 hops.
1       *       *       *       Request timed out.
2       *       *       *       Request timed out.
3       *       *       *       Request timed out.
4       *       *       *       Request timed out.
5       *       *       *       Request timed out.
6       *       *       *       Request timed out.
```

At least with my untrained eye, `tracetcp` and `telnet` are returning the same result: I cannot connect.

Am I missing something? How can `tracetcp` help me here?

Comment: Something between you and the remote server (could be literally anything including the endpoints) is blocking ICMP (this is annoyingly common for firewall appliances, clueless ISPs, and cargo-cult administrators), so there's no way to know why your connection is failing. Unless you have admin level access to a devices along the path there's nothing more you can do diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Does it make sense that if I want to connect to port 22 to an IP, and there are 5 hops, then I'm indirectly connecting to all 5 IPs also through port 22?

Comment: No, you're not connecting to all the intermediate hops. Your traffic is simply passing through those hops to the destination.